# Non-exhaustive patterns in function ships

Tags: haskell

I got this exception, anyone know how to get rid of it?
`

> *** Exception: hw.hs:(33,1)-(35,53): Non-exhaustive patterns in function ships`

All functions are working fine except for function `ships`.
Its probably something with the list of Tuples, but I can't figure it out. Here is the code:

```
replace :: Char -> Char
replace c   | c == ' ' = '.'
            | c == '.' = '.'
            | otherwise = 'x';

findChar :: String -> Int -> String
findChar [] y = []
findChar (s:ss) y | y==0 = replace s : findChar ss (y-1)
                | otherwise = ' ' : findChar ss (y-1)

findStr :: Result -> Int -> Int -> Result
findStr [] x y = []
findStr (a:as) x y | x == 0 =  findChar a y : findStr as (x-1) y
                    | otherwise = findChar a (-1) : findStr as (x-1) y

ships :: Result -> [(Int, Int)] -> Result
ships [] [] = []
ships arena ((x,y):xs) = ships (findStr arena x y) xs
```

Comment: What do you think the function does if the first input is a non-empty list and the second is empty?

Comment: @RobinZigmond How could I not see it... Thanks mate

Comment: Keep warnings enabled: GHC can report the cases which are not handled. It's very convenient to have the compiler warn us with something like `missing pattern (_:_) []`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @chi has mentioned, turning on the `-Wall` option when compiling can be very useful for catching these problems at compile time instead of run time.  You can either include `-Wall` in the GHC command line, or you can add the pragma:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}
```

at the top of your source code to turn it on.

And, as @RobinZigmond has pointed out, your `ships` function handles the case where both functions are empty lists *and* the case where the second function is non-empty list, but unless you're positive that `ships` can never be called as `ships nonEmptyList []`, you've missed a case!

```
ships :: Result -> [(Int, Int)] -> Result
ships [] [] = []
ships _  [] = ?????  -- what happens here?
ships arena ((x,y):xs) = ships (findStr arena x y) xs
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That `-Wall` thing really helped me :)